# Can I trust sizeof(size_t) <= sizeof(unsigned long int) is always true?

Tags: c, size-type

Can I trust `sizeof(size_t) <= sizeof(unsigned long int)` is always true, according to C89 standard?

i.e., I will not loos value if I use a `unsigned long` where `size_t` is expected and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the best explanation of what happens with `size_t` and integer types in **C89** is the rationale document of it. Read carefully the section 3.4.4 of this document:

[Sizeof and size_t for C89 (rationale)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/rationale/c3.html#size-95t-3-3-3-4)

The 3rd paragraph says that:

> The type of sizeof, whatever it is, is published (in the library
>   header )  as size_t, since it is useful for the programmer
>   to be able to refer to this type.  This requirement implicitly
>   restricts size_t to be a synonym for an existing unsigned integer
>   type, thus quashing any notion that the largest declarable object
>   might be too big to span even with an unsigned long.

This means that, for the concern of **C89**, in general `size_t` is the same as a preexisting `unsigned` integer type, what in C89 implies one of the `unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long`.
In particular, every value of type `size_t` is in the range of `unsigned long`.
By reading the specifications of the standard C89, you can see also that `sizeof(size_t)<=sizeof(long)`.

---

Now, the situation in **C99** is a little different. This standard says that:

1. 7.17 par. 2 `size_t` is an unsigned integer type.
2. 7.17 par. 4 The types used for `size_t` [...] should not have an integer conversion rank greater than that of `signed long int`
3. --------- unless the implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary.
4. 6.2.5 par. 8 For any two integer types with the same signedness and different integer conversion rank (see 6.3.1.1), the range of values of the type with smaller integer conversion rank is a subrange of the values of the other type.

   Since the **integer conversion rank** of `signed long int` is the same that `unsigned long int`, this implies that the range of values of `size_t` is contained in the range of values of `unsigned long int`. 
   But the item 3 in the list above left the door open to exceptions to this rule.

So, we can only say that is highly intended that an implementation makes the values of `size_t` hold in the range of the `unsigned long int`. But we cannot be **completely sure**.

If you want to be sure, you can do the following procedure to check your system:

1. Include the files `<limits.h>` and `<stdint.h>` in order to access the information about integer types for your implementation.
2. Compare the constants `ULONG_MAX` (from `<limits.h>`) and `SIZE_MAX` (from `<stdint.h>`).

A short program would be this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include <stdint.h>

 int main(void) {
      printf("Is the range of size_t containd in that of unsigned long?\n\n");
      if (SIZE_MAX <= ULONG_MAX)
           printf("Yes");
      else 
           printf("No");
      return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`According to the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), size_t is an unsigned integer type of at least 16 bit (see sections 7.17 and 7.18.3).`

So `sizeof(size_t) <= sizeof(unsigned long int)` is true, but `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(unsigned long int)` is not true and can lead to data loss. For instance:

```
size_t a = b;
```

may cause data loss if `b` is an `unsigned long int` since its value can be grater than an `size_t` can hold.

Comment: Your answer seems ambiguous, because your assert `sizeof(size_t) <= sizeof(unsigned long int)` implies that `izeof(size_t) > sizeof(unsigned long int)` is always false, but you are implying that "it is possible true". Besides The Mask asked about **C89** standard, and not **C89**.

Comment: Fix: "and not **C99**"

Comment: @pablo1977 It is not ambiguous, it is actually wrong. I will fix that. About the standard, I was aware but since the `long int` and others are defined with `int` as a referential, I think my answer is still valid.