# C cast void * to type_t

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have following code from an object-oriented programming C book:

```
{
  struct Set { int count; };

  struct Set * set =  malloc(sizeof(struct Set));
  void * p = set;

  const size_t size = * (const size_t *) p;
}
```

I cant understand how and why last line works. `size_t size` is dereferenced value of pointer of type `size_t`. pointer of type type_t is cast from `void* p`.
What is happening when I cast `void*` to `type_t*`, I could not find any information in the book or online tutorials. Can someone explain it to me or refer me to a good tutorial?

Comment: Format your code first, please.

Comment: "object-oriented programming C book" feels very very strange to me ... What's that book called?

Comment: Its "Object-oriented programming with Ansi-C" by Axel-Tobias Schreiner. It was recommended here in some stackoverflow questions.

Comment: anyone who are interested may find the book [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/351756/995714) or easily around the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what happens here is the following: You have a pointer to a structure (`p`) and you cast it to a `const size_t *` pointer, and use the value resulted. Supposedly the value should be the same as the value of `p->count` however do not really count on this. According to [Can I trust sizeof(size_t) <= sizeof(unsigned long int) is always true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329860/can-i-trust-sizeofsize-t-sizeofunsigned-long-int-is-always-true) `int` and `size_t` must not have the same size, so you well might end up with accessing memory which is not yours.

Comment: The link you point to says that size_t will not necessarily be the same size as a long int, but that it " implicitly restricts size_t to be a synonym for an existing unsigned integer type", which is the same size as an int

Comment: OK thank you i finally understood. The code is depending on that struct Set contains single int. I thought that in the last line some magic happends and size contains always the size of struct Set nomatter how big that struct is.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `void * p` is being casted to `const size_t *` type and used as the initializer for the  `const size_t size` variable. The value in the address [of type const `size_t` ]held by `p`  is being used.

Comment: so that casting is the same as sizeof(p) ?

Comment: @user3597496 how come? `cast` relates with type whereas sizeof() is an operator.

Answer (score 0):

When you cast void* p to size_t* p you are telling the compiler that p is pointing to a value of type size_t

In fact p is pointing to a a Set structure, which happens to contain a single int. The code is assuming that the type size_t is the same size as int, which the [standard seems to suggest it will be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19330742/259)

However size_t is unsigned, so if the value in the int is negative it will not be read correctly. Currently the data in the Set structure is uninitialised, so the result will be random